# javascript layerX and event.layerX in CSS3 transform: translate

Tags: javascript

I put it（red box） center and  up and down, left and right, and I want to get the let position, which is currently negative, how do you solve that?

**this is javascript and css  and html:**

```js
   var foo = document.getElementsByClassName("div")[0];
   foo.onclick = function(e){
    var ev = window.event || e;
    console.log("is："+ev.layerX);
   }
```

```css
   *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   }
   html,body{
    background: #CCCCCC;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   }
   #test{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background: red;
   }
   #test .div{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>

 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="test">
   <div class="div"></div>
  </div>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFB6G.png)

**why left: -2  -45  .....??

I want it(left) have : 1 5  3  45**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you need is **ev.clientX**. It will give the position related to the window. If you want the position related to the **div** you should substract the **div**'s *x*.

```js
   var foo = document.getElementsByClassName("div")[0];
   foo.onclick = function(e){
    var ev = window.event || e;
                                var div = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log("is："+ (ev.clientX - div.left));
   }
```

```css
   *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   }
   html,body{
    background: #CCCCCC;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   }
   #test{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background: red;
   }
   #test .div{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>

 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="test">
   <div class="div"></div>
  </div>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: chrome  lef:862 

firefox  lef:527

The Numbers are different. I want to start at 0

Comment: THINKYOU~~~~~~~~~~ :)